# Not able to generate rubberband effect when i try to hover quickly around the letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

i have achieved the rubber band effect for the letters when i hover using animate.css library and the problem is the letters wont be able to have any rubberband effect but the color is changing  when i hover quickly over the letters is there anything stopping i dont understand.

This is my code for the rubber band effect of the letters

```
  const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate');
  const [showBlobs, setShowBlobs] = useState(false); 
  const hiArray = ['H', 'i,'];
  const imArray = ['I', ' ', 'a', 'm'];
  const nameArray = ['u', 'm', 'a', 'n', 't', 'h'];
  const jobArray = ['W', 'e', 'b'];
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setLetterClass(prevLetterClass =>
        prevLetterClass === 'text-animate' ? 'text-animate-hover' : 'text-animate'
      );
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);
return(
            <div className="hero-info">
          <h1 className="text-4xl lg:text-6xl">
            <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass} strArray={hiArray} idx={10} />{' '}
            <br />
            <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass} strArray={imArray} idx={14} />{' '}
            <span className={`${letterClass} _16 text-accent`}>S</span>
            <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass} strArray={nameArray} idx={17} /> <br />
            <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass} strArray={jobArray} idx={23} />{' '}
            <span ref={textRef}></span>
          </h1>
        </div>
)
```

i will be attaching the .scss code for the rubber band effect

```
.text-animate {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    min-width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.text-animate-hover {
    min-width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    cursor: pointer;
  
    &:hover {
      animation: rubberBand 1s ;
      color: #37e4db;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.